# How to change current working directory and set environment variable using paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I would like to ssh to another server to run some script.

But before I run the script, I need to change directory to the path where the script is locate and set some environment variables.

In my local host, it can be done by

```
os.chdir(path)
os.environ["xxx"] = "xxx"
```

But in paramiko, I am not sure if any method can accomplish the things above. The closest thing I found is

```
ssh.exec_command("cd /xxx/yyy;xxx.sh")
```

But I would not like to execute several commands connect together with **;** .

Would like to ask is there any other way that can change directory/set environment variables when ssh using paramiko?

Answer (score 0):

For environment variables I could not get them to be set, however using an interactive shell will load the environment variables of the user. Those you can change in the .bashrc file.

For how to set up an interactive shell:
http://snipplr.com/view/12940/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a solution yet for how to change the host directory; like you, I've been trying to use `sshClient.exec_command("cd " + directory_name)`, but to no effect.

However, I can help with you question of issuing multiple commands. You could simply call `sshClient.exec_command("command1; command2; command3;")`. Alternatively, you could create a helper method such as:

```
def execCmd(ssh_client, *commands):
    for command in commands:
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(command)
        for line in stdout.readlines():
            print line
        for line in stderr.readlines():
            print line

cmds = [command1,command2,command3]
execCmd(SSH_Client,*cmds)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use '|' pipe to combine different commands.
It will work with ssh.exec_command().

Comment: This is only correct if the intent is to pass the output of the first command as input to the second.  It does not help at all for the OP's question.